# Jenkins build always returns to Gradle 3.5 Wrapper

Tags: gradle, jenkins, grails

Trying to build a Grails 5.3.2 project with SDKs provided by SDKMan, Jenkins stops with the following error:

```
| Error Command [war] error: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip'. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip'.
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:83)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_runBuildWithConsoleOutput_closure3.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:97)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.doCall(GradleUtil.groovy:78)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil$_withProjectConnection_closure1.call(GradleUtil.groovy)
  at grails.io.support.SystemOutErrCapturer.withNullOutput(SystemOutErrCapturer.groovy:64)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.withProjectConnection(GradleUtil.groovy:77)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleUtil.runBuildWithConsoleOutput(GradleUtil.groovy:92)
  at org.grails.cli.gradle.GradleInvoker.invokeMethod(GradleInvoker.groovy:50)
  at assemble.run(assemble.groovy:21)
  at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:153)
  at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:475)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:377)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:350)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
  at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
```

The point may be that Gradle 3.5 is not suitable here, I am made to believe.
In the buildscript, there is:

```
export GRADLE_USER_HOME="/var/lib/jenkins/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/7.5.1/bin"
sdk use java 11.0.12-open
sdk use grails 5.3.2
sdk use gradle 7.5.1
```

and the build log confirms that these settings are being used:

```
[1;32mUsing java version 11.0.12-open in this shell.[0m
[1;32mUsing gradle version 7.5.1 in this shell.[0m
[1;32mUsing grails version 5.3.2 in this shell.[0m
...
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod (file:/var/lib/jenkins/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/7.5.1/bin/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5-all/exhrs6ca08n232b14ue48lbye/gradle-3.5/lib/gradle-base-services-3.5.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackages()
```

`gradle.properties` configures: `gradleWrapperVersion=7.5.1`.

`gradle-wrapper.properties` configures:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

In a former Grails 3 version of the project, `gradle.properties` was in fact configuring `gradleWrapperVersion=3.5`. The Grails 3 build has been successful on the same Jenkins instance. Trying to avoid side effects from the Jenkins Grails 3 project build, I have added `cleanWs()` to `stage('Build')` of the `Jenkinsfile`.

- What is the problem here?
- Why does the build always refer back to Gradle wrapper 3.5? Where can I change this? I can't find no reference to version 3.5 in [the
  project's Grails 5 branch](https://github.com/openlibraryenvironment/gokb/tree/g5-deployOnQA/server/gokbg3/) which I am deploying.
- Are there any config options in Jenkins that I am missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There were two major configuration mistakes in my Jenkins build configuration.

The first one was that `GRADLE_USER_HOME` was set to the Gradle SDK, but it must be set the directory containing `gradle.properties`.

The second one, responsible for the Gradle 3.5 error message, was that I have two build jobs in parallel, an older one using Grails 3 (with Gradle 3.5) and this one, using Grails 5 (with Gradle 7.5.1). At a `cd` command in my build script, I accidentally used the path of the older build job.

With these mistakes being fixed, minor corrections were easy and now I have a successful build.